# Copy Workitem With TFS Rest API

Tags: rest, tfs-2015

Is there a way to **'copy'** a workitem using the rest api? Like the option in visual studio?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default way to achieve copying a workitem using the rest api. Instead, you can use Rest API to [get the work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item) that you want to copy, then modify the information you want (like Work item type) and then [create a new work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) base on the new information.

**Get a work item:**

```
GET http://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

**Create a work item:**

```
PATCH http://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork",
    "value": x
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "xx\\xx\\xx"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
    "value": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "xx"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "value": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Related",
      "url": "http://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/xx",
    }
  }
]
```